# Next Previous Product Postion in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am creating Next and Previous button in Product Pages so that when I click on them I can navigate to the next or previous product of the category, In Magento how can I get the product position? I am using Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an observer for loading products from product listing block/page. Then create helper methods for previous and next product's position.

Here is the **[Inchoo_Prevnext](https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_Prevnext)** extension created by Branko Ajzele. For details take a look at the Inchoo's [official blog post](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/listing-out-previousnext-products-in-magento-inchoo_prevnext-extension/)
 .

Comment: thank you for your link, but it's not working in Magento 1.9

Comment: i think you are using your custom package/theme. please follow the rules. 1 copy layout file `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/inchoo_prevnext.xml` to `app/design/frontend/your-package/your-thme/layout/inchoo_prevnext.xml` and 2) copy inchoo folder from `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/inchoo` to `app/design/frontend/your-package/your-themet/template/inchoo`. it would be some css problem but its working.

Comment: can you show me some of your screenshots because i can not see the button, thank a lot

Comment: I checked on magento 1.9.1.0. Please to this link http://postimg.org/image/owqwsrhkz/ . Here it shows next-previous button with product name and images. you may hide name and images.